# Python List selecting from back

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I want alternate digits starting from second to last i.e `[6,4,2]` .

I tried `a[:-1:-2]` but I dont get the correct output.

Comment: You start at index 0 going to index -1. That is from the first element to last with a step of -2. It's no wonder you are getting nothing in the slice.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> a[-2::-2]
[6, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the slice in the format `list[start:end:step]` so use the following instead:

```
a[-2::-2] # start at the second to last, to to the end by backing up 2
```

You are in fact going from at the beginning to the end stepping back by twos, thus getting nothing.

Comment: For a `list` with an even length, this will omit the first element (e.g. `list(range(1,9))[-2:0:-2]` produces `[7, 5, 3]` instead of `[7, 5, 3, 1]`).

Comment: Does that mean it assumes only `list`s of odd lengths?

Comment: Nevermind, you are correct. I don't really understand why yours works and mine doesn't. Isn't the zero implied?

Comment: The zero isn't implied; it's the same as `[1,2,3][:]` vs `[1,2,3][:-1]`. It starts from the start, inclusive, then goes to the end, non-inclusive.

Comment: Oh, so it's the exclusion which differs the two?

Comment: Yes, just like `range(10)` doesn't include 10 and `range(10,0,-1)` doesn't include 0.